# How to combine Cause Specific Hazard model

Tags: survival, competing-risks, cause-specific

Lets say I need to model the survival probability for death from heart disease (noted $H$). There is a competing risk in the study which is non-heart disease (noted $NH$). $H$ and $NH$ are competing risks, we want to model $H$ in presence of $NH$.

I've adopted the Cause-Specific Hazard model, to model the hazard rate of one risk, considering the other is censoring. So I have calculated:

$$\lambda^H_t = \lambda^H_0 * exp(X^T *\beta^H)$$
$$\lambda^{NH}_t = \lambda^{NH}_0 * exp(X^T *\beta^{NH})$$

So I'm able to calculate the overall (global) survival function:

$$S_t = exp(-\int_0^t (\lambda^H_t + \lambda^{NH}_t) dt$$

But what I need to calculate is **not the overall $S_t$, but the $S^H_t$**, the survival function of the death from heart disease (ND), considering ND as competing risk (which is not just $exp(-\int_0^t \lambda^H_t dt$)

How can I do this?

Comment: See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf

Comment: @FrankHarrell thanks for the document. But sorry I didn't find the answer to my question. They only mentioned the Fine-Gray as an alternative, but does not show how to combine two model to calculate the $S^H_t$